# How to install DNX Secret Manager in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm developing with ASP.NET5 on Mac OS X. I want to implement OAuth and use Secret Manager to store my secret configuration, so I'm following this DNXSecret Configuration page.
https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-Secret-Configuration

But, after following the instructions, I couldn't successfully install `user-secret` command to my Mac, and I'm pretty much stuck.

As the first step, I installed DNVM and confirmed `dnvm list` command returns Mono as the runtime engine.

```
$ dnvm list
Active Version              Runtime Arch Location             Alias
------ -------              ------- ---- --------             -----
  *    1.0.0-beta4          mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      default
```

I also installed Yeoman, Grunt, Bower etc, and `dnu restore` command worked fine. I successfully showed a Yeoman scaffolded ASP.NET5 page both locally and on Azure.

Then I started to install Secret Manager, following the above page. In the beginning, the following command failed:

```
dnu commands install SecretManager
```

with the error below:

```
Errors in /Users/<username>/.dnx/bin/packages/SecretManager/1.0.0-beta4/app/project.json
Unable to locate SecretManager >= 1.0.0-beta4-10173
```

So, I modified the above 'project.json' file in its "dependencies" block as:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ASP.NET 5 tool to manage user secrets.",
  "dependencies": {
    "SecretManager": "1.0.0-beta4"    // <<- modified here
    //"SecretManager": "1.0.0-beta4-10173"
  },
  "commands": {
    "user-secret": "SecretManager"
  },
  "userSecretsId": "testuserSecretsId",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*"
      }
    }
  },
  "entryPoint": "SecretManager",
  "loadable": false
}
```

(before) "SecretManager": "1.0.0-beta4-10173"
(after) "SecretManager": "1.0.0-beta4"

Then the command finished successfully and SecretManager seems to be installed with the result below:

```
konishis-air:AspNetSocialLoginTest Ryuji$ dnu commands install SecretManager
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='SecretManager'.
  OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='SecretManager' 1674ms
Restoring packages for /Users/Ryuji/.dnx/bin/packages/e27d166dcf594105be47fff78420df10/project.json
Writing lock file /Users/Ryuji/.dnx/bin/packages/e27d166dcf594105be47fff78420df10/project.lock.json
Restore complete, 246ms elapsed
Restoring packages for /Users/Ryuji/.dnx/bin/packages/SecretManager/1.0.0-beta4/app/project.json
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='System.Console'.
  OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='System.Console' 1395ms
Writing lock file /Users/Ryuji/.dnx/bin/packages/SecretManager/1.0.0-beta4/app/project.lock.json
Restore complete, 1751ms elapsed
The following commands were installed: .project.json, user-secret
```

However, when I run `user-secret` command, I get 'command not found'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, that is a known issue and we've fixed in beta5.

You have two options:

1. Pass the fallback source: `dnu commands install secretmanager 1.0.0-beta4 -f https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetrelease/api/v2`
2. Update to the latest beta5 bits

Comment: Thanks @Victor for the quick answer. I tried the No.1 and still `user-secret` was missing. After doing some staff I found `user-secret` under `~/.dnx/bin` sitting there, and I'm not sure if this command was placed due to the No.1 workaround. Should I just add this to the system path or it's supposed to be added by `dnu` command?  Also I did a brief search but I couldn't figure out how to install DNX beta5 to Mac. Could you just tell me a hint?

Comment: Ah, yeah. On mac, the `~/.dnx/bin` folder is not added to the `PATH`. We have a bug tracking that. You have to manually add it to the path.